# C++ protocol for sending arrays over TCP

Tags: c++, socket

As someone who has programmed in C for a long time, I have just written my first C++ program and feel it would be very valuable to get a review of the code, to see what features of C++ I could make more use of.

The program provides a protocol for sending and receiving arrays of data over TCP. The idea is to

```
i) Send/receive the dimension of the array.
ii) Send/receive the shape of the array.
iii) Send/receive the data of the array.
```

To run the code you can do the following

```
g++ protocol.cpp -o protocol
```

Then in separate terminals, for example

```
./protocol server int32 float32
```

and

```
./protocol client int32 float32
```

The program itself is below

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <endian.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int is_system_le() {
    // Test if the system is little endian.
    short int word = 0x0001;
    char *b = (char *) &word;

    // In the little endian case, 1 will be read as 1 in a character.
    if (b[0]) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

template <class int_T, class data_T>
class Array {
 public:
    // Fields.
    int_T size;
    int_T dim;
    int_T *shape;
    data_T *data;

    // Methods.
    Array(int size, int dim);
    ~Array(void);

    int allocate(void);
};

template <class int_T, class data_T>
Array<int_T, data_T>::Array(int size, int dim) {
    // Set fields.
    this->size = size;
    this->dim = dim;
}

template <class int_T, class data_T>
int Array<int_T, data_T>::allocate() {
    // Create memory necessary for the array.
    this->shape = new int[dim];
    this->data = new data_T[size];

    return 0;
}

template <class int_T, class data_T>
Array<int_T, data_T>::~Array() {
    // Delete the created memory.
    delete[] shape;
    delete[] data;
}

class Protocol {
 public:
    // Class constants.
    static const int CHUNK_BYTES = 1024;

    // Fields.
    std::string socket_type;
    int verbose;

    // Methods.
    Protocol(std::string socket_type, int verbose);
    ~Protocol(void);

    int plisten(std::string host, int port);
    int pconnect(std::string host, int port);
    int pclose();

    template <class int_T, class data_T>
    int psend(
        Array<int_T, data_T> *arr,
        std::string int_format,
        std::string data_format
    );

    template <class int_T, class data_T>
    int preceive(
        Array<int_T, data_T> *arr,
        std::string int_format,
        std::string data_format
    );

 private:
    // Fields.
    int sock;
    int conn;

    // Methods.
    template <class int_T, class data_T>
    int psend_tcp(
        Array<int_T, data_T> *arr,
        std::string int_format,
        std::string data_format
    );

    template <class int_T, class data_T>
    int preceive_tcp(
        Array<int_T, data_T> *arr,
        std::string int_format,
        std::string data_format
    );
};

// Member functions.
Protocol::Protocol(std::string socket_type, int verbose) {
    if (verbose) {
        std::cout << "Protocol object created." << std::endl;
    }
    this->socket_type = socket_type;
    this->verbose = verbose;
}

Protocol::~Protocol(void) {
    if (verbose) {
        std::cout << "Protocol object deleted." << std::endl;
    }
}

int Protocol::plisten(std::string host, int port) {
    // Listen for a connection on the host/port.
    if (socket_type.compare("server") != 0) {
        throw "Error: Can only listen with server sockets.";
    }

    // Create the socket.
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    // Set up host address structure (don't understand this).
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host.c_str());
    memset(server_addr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof(server_addr.sin_zero));

    // Bind to host port.
    bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));

    // Listen for connection.
    if (verbose) {
        std::cout << "Listening for connections." << std::endl;
    }
    listen(sock, 1);

    // Accept a connection.
    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
    socklen_t client_addr_len = sizeof(client_addr);
    conn = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, &client_addr_len);
    if (verbose) {
        std::cout << "Accepted connection." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}


int Protocol::pconnect(std::string host, int port) {
    // Connect to an actual socket.
    if (socket_type.compare("client") != 0) {
        throw "Error: Can only connect with client sockets.";
    }

    // Create the socket.
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    // Set up host address structure (don't understand this).
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host.c_str());
    memset(server_addr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof(server_addr.sin_zero));

    // Try to connect.
    if (verbose) {
        std::cout << "Trying to connect." << std::endl;
    }
    connect(
        sock,
        (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr,
        sizeof(server_addr)
    );
    if (verbose) {
        std::cout << "Accepted connection." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}


int Protocol::pclose() {
    // Close a created server or client socket.
    if (socket_type.compare("server") == 0) {
        if (verbose) {
            std::cout << "Closing server socket." << std::endl;
        }

        close(sock);
    } else if (socket_type.compare("client") == 0) {
        if (verbose) {
            std::cout << "Closing client socket." << std::endl;
        }
        shutdown(sock, SHUT_WR);
        close(sock);
    }

    return 0;
}

template <class int_T, class data_T>
int Protocol::psend(Array<int_T, data_T> *arr, std::string int_format, std::string data_format) {
    // Send data in arr across the network.
    int ack;

    ack = psend_tcp(arr, int_format, data_format);

    if (ack != 0) {
        throw "Did not receive good acknowledgement after sending data.";
    }

    return 0;
}

template <class int_T, class data_T>
int Protocol::psend_tcp(Array<int_T, data_T> *arr, std::string int_format, std::string data_format) {
    // Send data in arr across the network using TCP.

    // This can certainly be cleaned up by using templates and factoring out
    // the function for sending chunked data over the network.

    // Note we always use little endian.
    uint8_t buffer[1024];
    size_t buffer_byte_size;

    // Server sends over conn, client over sock.
    int send_sock;
    if (socket_type.compare("server") == 0) {
        send_sock = conn;
    } else if (socket_type.compare("client") == 0) {
        send_sock = sock;
    }

    // i) Send the integer dimensions.
    if (int_format.compare("int32") == 0) {
        int32_t little_endian_int = (int32_t) htole32((uint32_t) arr->dim);
        memcpy(
            &buffer[0],
            &little_endian_int,
            sizeof(little_endian_int)
        );
        buffer_byte_size = sizeof(int32_t);
    } else if (int_format.compare("int64") == 0) {
        int64_t little_endian_int = (int64_t) htole64((uint64_t) arr->dim);
        memcpy(
            &buffer[0],
            &little_endian_int,
            sizeof(little_endian_int)
        );
        buffer_byte_size = sizeof(int64_t);
    }

    if (verbose) {
        std::cout << "Sending dimensions: " << int_format << std::endl;
    }
    send(send_sock, buffer, buffer_byte_size, 0);

    // ii) Send the integer shape. May need to be done in multiple chunks.
    if (int_format.compare("int32") == 0) {
        buffer_byte_size = sizeof(int32_t);
    } else if (int_format.compare("int64") == 0) {
        buffer_byte_size = sizeof(int64_t);
    }

    // Make sure our arr->shape is stored in int_format. In future can maybe
    // auto-fix by converting it.
    if (sizeof(int_T) != buffer_byte_size) {
        throw "Error: Array integers not in int_format so cannot send.";
    }

    // Make sure our host system is little endian as we don't bother converting
    // here. We could theoretically write to a buffer at convert.
    if (!is_system_le()) {
        throw "Currently rely on the system being little endian.";
    }
    int reps = arr->dim * buffer_byte_size/CHUNK_BYTES;
    int leftover = arr->dim * buffer_byte_size % CHUNK_BYTES;
    if (verbose) {
        std::cout << "Sending shape: " << int_format << std::endl;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<reps; i++) {
        memcpy(
            &buffer[0],
            &arr->shape[i*CHUNK_BYTES/buffer_byte_size],
            CHUNK_BYTES
        );
        send(send_sock, buffer, CHUNK_BYTES, 0);
    }

    // Send leftover bytes.
    memcpy(
        &buffer[0],
        &arr->shape[reps*CHUNK_BYTES/buffer_byte_size],
        leftover
    );
    send(send_sock, buffer, leftover, 0);

    // iii) Send the array data (I'm not sure if we can be sure of float and
    //      double size). Requires converting to data_format.
    if (data_format.compare("int32") == 0) {
        buffer_byte_size = sizeof(int32_t);
    } else if (data_format.compare("int64") == 0) {
        buffer_byte_size = sizeof(int64_t);
    } else if (data_format.compare("float32") == 0) {
        buffer_byte_size = sizeof(float);
    } else if (data_format.compare("float64") == 0) {
        buffer_byte_size = sizeof(double);
    }

    if (sizeof(data_T) != buffer_byte_size) {
        throw "Error: Array data not in data_format so cannot send.";
    }

    reps = arr->size * buffer_byte_size/CHUNK_BYTES;
    leftover = arr->size * buffer_byte_size % CHUNK_BYTES;
    if (verbose) {
        std::cout << "Sending data: " << data_format << std::endl;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<reps; i++) {
        memcpy(
            &buffer[0],
            &arr->data[i*CHUNK_BYTES/buffer_byte_size],
            CHUNK_BYTES
        );
        send(send_sock, buffer, CHUNK_BYTES, 0);
    }

    // Send lefotver bytes.
    memcpy(
        &buffer[0],
        &arr->data[reps*CHUNK_BYTES/buffer_byte_size],
        leftover
    );
    send(send_sock, buffer, leftover, 0);

    // Receive acknowledgement.
    recv(send_sock, buffer, 1, 0);

    return buffer[0];
}

template <class int_T, class data_T>
int Protocol::preceive(Array<int_T, data_T> *arr, std::string int_format, std::string data_format) {
    // Put the received value into arr.
    preceive_tcp(arr, int_format, data_format);

    return 0;
}

template <class int_T, class data_T>
int Protocol::preceive_tcp(Array <int_T, data_T> *arr, std::string int_format, std::string data_format) {
    // Receive network data over TCP.

    // Note we always use little endian.
    uint8_t buffer[1024];
    size_t buffer_byte_size;

    // Server receives over conn, client over sock.
    int send_sock;
    if (socket_type.compare("server") == 0) {
        send_sock = conn;
    } else if (socket_type.compare("client") == 0) {
        send_sock = sock;
    }

    // i) Receive integer dimension.
    if (int_format.compare("int32") == 0) {
        buffer_byte_size = sizeof(int32_t);
    } else {
        buffer_byte_size = sizeof(int64_t);
    }

    if (buffer_byte_size != sizeof(int_T)) {
        throw "Tried to receive data into an array with wrong integer format";
    }
    recv(send_sock, buffer, buffer_byte_size, 0);

    if (int_format.compare("int32") == 0) {
        int32_t little_endian_int = (int32_t) le32toh(((uint32_t *) buffer)[0]);
        arr->dim = (int) little_endian_int;
    } else if (int_format.compare("int64") == 0) {
        int64_t little_endian_int = (int64_t) le64toh(((uint64_t *) buffer)[0]);
        arr->dim = (int) little_endian_int;
    }

    if (verbose) {
        std::cout << "Received dimensions: " << arr->dim << std::endl;
    }

    // ii) Receive integer shape (may need to be done in chunks).
    arr->shape = new int[arr->dim];
    //arr->shape = (int_T *) malloc(arr->dim*sizeof(int_T));

    int reps = arr->dim * buffer_byte_size/CHUNK_BYTES;
    int leftover = arr->dim * buffer_byte_size % CHUNK_BYTES;
    for (int i=0; i<reps; i++) {
        recv(send_sock, &arr->shape[i*CHUNK_BYTES/buffer_byte_size], CHUNK_BYTES, 0);
    }

    // Recieve lefotver bytes.
    recv(send_sock, &arr->shape[reps*CHUNK_BYTES/buffer_byte_size], leftover, 0);

    if (verbose) {
        std::cout << "Received shape:" << std::endl;
        std::cout << " [";
        for (int i=0; i<arr->dim; i++) {
            std::cout << arr->shape[i];
            if (i != arr->dim - 1) {
                std::cout << ",";
            }
        }
        std::cout << "]" << std::endl;
    }

    // iii) Recieve data.
    if (data_format.compare("int32") == 0) {
        buffer_byte_size = sizeof(int32_t);
    } else if (data_format.compare("int64") == 0) {
        buffer_byte_size = sizeof(int64_t);
    } else if (data_format.compare("float32") == 0) {
        buffer_byte_size = sizeof(float);
    } else {
        buffer_byte_size = sizeof(double);
    }

    if (sizeof(data_T) != buffer_byte_size) {
        // Should check on full type not just bytes. Unfortunately don't know
        // how to do this in C++.
        throw "Error: Array data not in data_format so cannot receive.";
    }

    // Determine the size from the shape.
    arr->size = 1;
    for (int i=0; i<arr->dim; i++) {
        arr->size *= arr->shape[i];
    }

    arr->data = new data_T[arr->size];
    //arr->data = (data_T *) malloc(arr->size * sizeof(data_T));
    reps = arr->size * buffer_byte_size/CHUNK_BYTES;
    leftover = arr->size * buffer_byte_size % CHUNK_BYTES;
    for (int i=0; i<reps; i++) {
        recv(
            send_sock,
            &arr->data[i*CHUNK_BYTES/buffer_byte_size],
            CHUNK_BYTES,
            0
        );
    }

    // Receive leftover bytes.
    recv(
        send_sock,
        &arr->data[reps*CHUNK_BYTES/buffer_byte_size],
        leftover,
        0
    );

    if (verbose) {
        std::cout << "Received data:" << std::endl;
        if ((arr->size < 50) & (arr->dim == 2)) {
            for (int i=0; i<arr->shape[0]; i++) {
                for (int j=0; j<arr->shape[1]; j++) {
                    std::cout << arr->data[i*arr->shape[1] + j] << ", ";
                }
                std::cout << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }

    // No acknowledgement necessary for TCP however send anyway.
    buffer[0] = 0;
    send(send_sock, buffer, 1, 0);

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Declare the protocol.
    std::string socket_type;
    if (argc == 1) {
        std::cout << "No socket type provided so using server." << std::endl;
        socket_type = "server";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Using protocol type " << argv[1] << "." << std::endl;
        socket_type = argv[1];
    }
    Protocol cp(socket_type, 1);

    std::cout << "Total chunk bytes: " << cp.CHUNK_BYTES << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Socket Type: " << cp.socket_type << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Verbose: " << cp.verbose << std::endl;

    if (cp.socket_type.compare("server") == 0) {
        try {
            cp.plisten("127.0.0.1", 65432);
        } catch (const char *msg) {
            std::cerr << msg << std::endl;
        }

        // Now send some random data (5 x 2 array).
        Array<int, float> arr(10, 2);
        arr.allocate();

        arr.shape[0] = 5;
        arr.shape[1] = 2;

        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            if (!strcmp(argv[3], "float32") || !strcmp(argv[3], "float64")) {
                arr.data[i] = i + i*0.1;
            } else {
                arr.data[i] = i;
            }
        }
        cp.psend(&arr, argv[2], argv[3]);
    } else {
        try {
            cp.pconnect("127.0.0.1", 65432);
        } catch (const char *msg) {
            std::cerr << msg << std::endl;
        }

        // Now receive some random data.
        Array<int, float> arr(-1, -1);
        cp.preceive(&arr, argv[2], argv[3]);
    }

    cp.pclose();

    return 0;
}
```

**Notes**

1) One of the issues I had was that I felt it would be nicer for the `Protocol::preceive` method to return an `Array` instance but I didn't know how to pass the template to the method when none of the arguments used it. Instead I went for passing a pointer to an instance.

2) This had another issue that I wanted the `Array` constructor to allocate the memory necessary for holding the shape and data information. However the size of this memory is not known before the method is run. Hence I ended up not including this in my constructor. I would be interested in hearing if there is a way around this.

3) Note that a quirk of the program is that I have `Protocol::psend` and `Protocol::psend_tcp` methods (similarly for receiving). This is for a fairly good reason that I copied the logic of this program from a Python program I wrote that also allowed sending and receiving over UDP. I wanted to leave them like this in case I wanted to add this feature in future.

4) I thought it may be a good idea to wrap some of the C libraries (to do with sockets) in a namespace as I got quite a few name clashes (hence why I have the prefix `p` in all my methods). When I tried to do this however I ended up getting a compiler error so gave up and moved on.

Answer (score 2):

**Alternate Header Files**
In C++ if you want to include stdlib.h or string.h the proper include statements are

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
```

**C++ Container Classes**
In C++ there is [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) that provides a built in array with iterators that might prove helpful. [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) might be even more helpful since it is basically a variable sized array of any type.

[Iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator) have taken the place of pointers when using container classes. Iterators make for loops over containers safer because the container classes have 2 defined iterators as member, `begin` and `end`.

**Old Style C Casts Versus new C++ Casts**
C++ has 2 new forms of casting variables, [static_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) and [dynamic_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast). These casts perform error checking on the cast and make casting type safe. The cast in `int is_system_le()` is not type safe if it is changed to a static_cast. See the second answer of this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001307/detecting-endianness-programmatically-in-a-c-program) for a workaround to the cast.

The third answer to the stack overflow question suggests using `htonl()` as a library function that performs the same test and is portable.

Answer (score 2):

Reading your code is difficult because you have put all the features into a single class, the `Protocol`. It's better to split this class into several, each with its own responsibility.

Programming sockets using the C/POSIX API is something really ugly. You should hide away all these details in a class called `Socket` (and maybe a second class called `ServerSocket`). Then you can write:

```
Socket conn(host, port);
conn.psend("hello", 5);
if (!conn)
    std::cerr << "sending failed: " << conn.last_error() << "\n";
```

This is much nicer than dealing with raw sockets and `struct inaddr`.

On top of this `Socket` class you should build the `LowLevelProtocol` that knows how to encode an `int32_t` and in which order to send it over the wire:

```
LowLevelProtocol llproto(conn);
llproto.write_int32(12345678);
llproto.write_uint32(12345678);
```

Using this low-level protocol, you can finally build your encoding of arrays. At this point, you don't have to think about big endian or little endian anymore, you just tell the low-level protocol to *send this, send that*.

The benefit of this separation is that at each of these abstraction levels, there are only a few topics of interest. It easy to test these levels individually by connecting them to mocked-away objects that you only create during the test. For example, the `LowLevelProtocol` can not only write to a socket, it can also write to a `std::ostringstream`, and this one can be tested very easily.

Another benefit is that the high-level protocol now contains the rules of how an array is encoded, and nothing else. This makes it easy to understand this small part of the program.